# getting arguments in controller when calling it from twig template

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

I'm trying to access variables in my controller that I set in my function calling in twig. It actually looks like this:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Domain:show', {
        'test': 'ok'
})) }}
```

And in my controller it looks like this:

```
public function showAction(Request $request, $test = null)
{
    $test = $test ? $test : 'notOk';
    var_dump($test); // result "notOK"
    die;
}
```

My aim is to have `var_dump($test);` resulting in 'ok'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second argument of `controller()` in Twig is an array of request attributes.

https://github.com/symfony/twig-bridge/blob/master/Extension/HttpKernelExtension.php#L81

So that:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Domain:show', {
   'test': 'ok'
})) }}
```

should be available:

```
public function showAction(Request $request)
{
    return new Response($request->attributes->get('test'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a Response from a controller, var_dump will not show up in your rendered template:

```
public function showAction(Request $request, $test = null)
{
    $test = $test ? $test : 'notOk';
    return new Response($test);
}
```

other than that your example works for me as intended